# CollapsingToolbarLayout. How to set expandedTitlesTopMargin progrommaticly?

Tags: java, android, material-design

my Layout in xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            **app:expandedTitleMarginTop="@dimen/space_165dp"**
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
```

want to call from code app:expandedTitleMarginTop but theres is no such method

Answer (score 0):

Below is the API to set margin top programatically.

```
setExpandedTitleMarginTop
```

void setExpandedTitleMarginTop (int margin)
Sets the top expanded title margin in pixels.

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) for all available APIs.

Comment: i must call first CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: but its says is - Related XML Attributes:

Comment: resolved,need to change 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'